# UIImage Inverted (Transformation issue) due to CIDetector or CIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, core-image, face-detection

What i am doing is to detect the face by CIDetector and my image is coming from UIImagePickerController (capturing image from back Camera). I can detect face.. but my problem is that i get my face image inverted (up to down). Here is my [**CODE**](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2912).

**My Problem**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between lines 83 and 88. You're flipping the view and not flipping it back because you have the code commented out.

**Edited to add**

I see you are using the sample project from http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/

You're flipping the image view, but you aren't flipping the window to account for this flip.

**Edited to add again**

Okay - looking a bit more at the tutorial and sample code that you are using, it's the flipping of the window that you don't want. But you'll need to write your code differently.

A better example is provided at http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/22/ios-5-face-detection-with-core-image/ which has the image displayed using `drawInRect:` and the context translated for drawing the facial features.

Comment: that code (lines) not working in ViewController . " [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)]; " this is use for " [self.window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)]; " window

Comment: see that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154585/face-detection-issue-using-cidetector

Comment: if i flip my window then tool bar will also flipped